# My Facebook app shows error

Tags: facebook

Actually I am a newbie and know very less though learning. This is the error message:

> SSL connection error
>
> Unable to make a secure connection to the server.
>   This may be a problem with the server, or it may be requiring a client
>   authentication certificate that you don't have. Error 107
>   (net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR): SSL protocol error.

Please check this link to see the error message:

https://apps.facebook.com/webmartbd/

Comment: Your URL https://jewelrana.me/iframe/ is not accessible via SSL.  Have you set up an SSL certificate?  You are [required by Facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/497/) to have an SSL certificate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your hosting provider doesn't support SSL. I would ask them about this.